# Children's book series in which a device is used to view images

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

The first book in the series has the main character's parents travel back in time with him at which point they get trapped and he makes it back leaving him without his parents and unsure of where they are. I believe his father was some type of scientist who invented the time machine along with other various things. At one point the boy uses a mind-wiping device once a dinosaur comes back to his time, to make everyone who sees it forget.

The book came with a flat see-through circular device that when rotated against random arrays of black bars within the book, images would be revealed.

Sorry to be vague hopefully you know what the book is.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: If you are being intentionally vague, please give us all details. :) If you're worried about "spoilers", you can always hide them using "?>" at the beginning of a line to turn it into a spoiler quote.